# Why do I get "MySQL is not running but lock exists"?

Tags: mysql, locking

I am getting this error

> mysql is not running but lock exist

when I am checking the status of MySQL server. I have removed the lock files using following command:

```
rm /var/lock/subsys/mysql
```

but still I am getting same error.

Can anyone provide any input on this.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

try using the unix lsof command to see which program has the lock

```
lsof | grep mysql
```

EDIT:in fact, run lsof on the lock itself

```
lsof /var/lock/subsys/mysql
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error. It started after an unexpected server reboot. I saw there is a default /etc/my.cnf file which is not in use for my installation. The issue resolved when it renamed my.cnf as my.cnf_old

Answer (score 1):

For this similar error:

> service mysql status ERROR! MySQL is not running, but lock file
>   (/var/lock/subsys/mysql) exists

Follow these steps:

1. `rm /var/lock/subsys/mysql rm`:

   > remove regular empty file 
   >   /var/lock/subsys/mysql? y

   Press <kbd>y</kbd>
2. `/etc/init.d/mysql start`.

   If the error occurs again after starting MYSQL
   then execute `ps -ef | grep mysql`
3. Kill all processes of MySQL and repeat steps **1** & **2**.

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is a quite old, but I like to make notes on the ones that work for issue that I've experienced recently.  I was getting the following message, which lead me here:

> service mysql status ERROR! MySQL is not running, but lock file
> (/var/lock/subsys/mysql) exists

These are the steps that fixed my issues:

1. mv /etc/my.cnf /etc/my.cnf_old
2. rm /var/lock/subsys/mysql
3. /etc/init.d/mysql start

   Starting MySQL.210921 16:46:28 mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/lib/mysql/server001.err'.
   210921 16:46:28 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql. SUCCESS!